# React Navigation : Update screentitle when page data updated from redux react navigation V5.0

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

My stack screen title set with route.params each title is loaded from backend

```
<Stack.Screen
     name='MyDetailPage'
     component={MyDetailPage}
     options={({ route }) =>
              ({
                   title: route.params.detailPageTitle,
              })}
     />
```

When I have some modification on detail page, the page re-render and update the data on the page. However, the screenTitle (which also in the page data) is not updated.

How can I also update screenTitle with the page data along with the detail page data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `navigation.setOptions({title: "new title"})` function provided by react-navigation. You can read more about this [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/).